# Scribus Not Working Properly (elementary OS 5.0)

Tags: applications

In order to keep this post short, allow me to point you to a rather old Scribus bug report, which perfectly describes the problem. This specific bug has been fixed upstream, and is not present in Ubuntu 18.04.1, or Xubuntu 18.04.1, or Linux Mint 19. BUT, it is present in elementaryOS 5.0 which is very strange. It would be nice if someone provided some solution since it cripples an otherwise perfectly working package:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/scribus/+bug/177805

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the Scribus that comes with [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno) comes from Ubuntu

```
$ apt policy scribus
scribus:
  Instalados: (ninguno)
  Candidato:  1.4.6+dfsg-4build1
  Tabla de versión:
     1.4.6+dfsg-4build1 500
        500 http://cl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

---

### About the Question

Remove Scribus

```
sudo apt purge scribus
```

Install flatpak

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Add flathub repo to flatpak

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Install Scribus (a newer version - current **`Scribus 1.5.4`**)

```
sudo flatpak install flathub net.scribus.Scribus
```

---

What is `flatpak`?

https://flatpak.org/faq/

---

ref:

https://flathub.org/apps/details/net.scribus.Scribus

https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

You can just add Scribus PPA with:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa`

and after

`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`

, you'll have 1.4.7 version.

If you like you can install `scibus-ng` (version 1.5.4) from the same PPA.

```
sudo apt  install scibus-ng
```

---

### Note

If you get an error like "`command not found`" after using `add-apt-repository`. Just install `software-properties-common` and run again the previous command:

```
sudo apt  install software-properties-common
```